# JsonObjectRequest error

Tags: android, json

I'm getting an error for Request.Method on the "Method" part and it says "Cannot resolve symbol"and I don't know why. I'm trying to parse JSON to pull images from a website.

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getRequestUrl(10),
            (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()

    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            L.zT(this, response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: which version of Volley are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the wrong import. Check in your import declaration of `Request`, and make sure that is

```
com.android.volley.Request
```

and not something else